# Half circle progression bar with stripes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I would like to draw the following component for a progress bar:

[image: Progress half circle]

With my code so far I can draw the half circle with the stripes but I can not make the stripes stop at 1/3 of the circle, they go all the way to the end. Also how do I add the white background?
Here is my current code:

```
class HalfCircleProgressView: UIView {
    
    var progress: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    private let backgroundLayerOne = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2, y: bounds.height / 2 + 50)
        let radius = min(bounds.width + 150, bounds.height + 150) / 2 - 50
        let startAngle = Double.pi
        let endAngle = startAngle + progress * CGFloat(Double.pi)
        
       
    
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        path.lineWidth = 15
        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
        
        let stripePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        stripePath.lineWidth = 15
        let dashes: [CGFloat] = [52.5, 2]
        stripePath.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)
        UIColor.red.setStroke()
        stripePath.stroke()
    }
}
```

This is what my current progress bar looks like at 80% progress:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple suggestions...

First, instead of hard-coding size/position values, keep the `HalfCircleProgressView` at a `2:1` ratio and make your arc fit the view exactly:

[image]

You can then embed that view in a "container":

[image]

and place other elements (labels, etc) relative to the `HalfCircleProgressView`:

[image]

and set the background to clear:

[image]

Next, use `CAShapeLayer` instead of overriding `draw()`:

- one layer for a white "background" arc
- one layer for a red "foreground" arc
- one layer for the "tick-marks"

There are several advantages to using a `CAShapeLayer` -- for your particular needs, the biggest one is that we can use the `.strokeEnd` property to "automatically manage" the foreground arc and its "percentage" complete.

So, if the background and foreground "arc" layers use the same path and lineWidth properties:

[image]

[image]

When we want to set the red "progress" arc to, say, 25%, we set:

```
foregroundLayer.strokeEnd = 0.25
```

[image]

and for 80%:

```
foregroundLayer.strokeEnd = 0.8
```

[image]

No need to calculate angles from percentages and re-draw everything.

So, what about the "tick marks"?

Well, it looks like you want marks at (I'm guessing):

```
210° / 230° / 250° / 270° / 290° / 310° / 330°
```

Instead of using a mask pattern on the foreground arc, we'll use a bezier path with line segments as the `.cgPath` of our "tick-marks" shape layer.

[image]

Shape layer paths are stroked "on the mid-line" so we need to loop through the "gap" steps calculate the point-at-angle on the "outer edge" of the 15-point thick arc, calculate the point-at-angle on the "inner edge," and then `.move(to:)` and `.addLine(to:)`.

We *could* write some math for those calculations... or, we can ***"cheat"*** and take advantage of the `.currentPoint` property of a `UIBezierPath`!

When we manipulate a path like this:

```
let bez = UIBezierPath()
bez.move(to: pt)
bez.addArc(withCenter: c, radius: r, startAngle: a1, endAngle: a2, clockwise: true)
```

we can get the "end-point" of that arc with:

```
bez.currentPoint
```

So, to add the line segments, we'll create an "outerPath" with a radius of `radius PLUS lineWidth * 0.5` and an "innerPath" with a radius of `radius MINUS lineWidth * 0.5`. We then start each path with an `.addArc` to the angle of the first tick and loop seven times (for 7 tick marks)... each time through the loop incrementing the angle and adding line segments:

```
    // 20-degree tick spacing
    let angleInc: CGFloat = .pi / 9.0

    // start at 270-degrees minus 4 * spacing
    var angle: CGFloat = .pi * 1.5 - angleInc * 4.0

    for _ in 1...7 {
        tickOuterPath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: tickOuterRadius, startAngle: angle, endAngle: angle + angleInc, clockwise: true)
        tickInnerPath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: tickInnerRadius, startAngle: angle, endAngle: angle + angleInc, clockwise: true)
        tickPath.move(to: tickOuterPath.currentPoint)
        tickPath.addLine(to: tickInnerPath.currentPoint)
        angle += angleInc
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

all the way to the 7th loop:

[image]

of course, we won't **see** those extra paths:

[image]

So our custom view now looks like this at 100%:

[image]

and at 33%:

[image]

and at 78.27%:

[image]

---

Here is some sample code you can play with:

```
class HalfCircleProgressView: UIView {
    
    public var progress: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            // keep progress between 0.0 and 1.0
            progress = max(0.0, min(1.0, progress))
            // update layer stroke end
            foregroundLayer.strokeEnd = progress
        }
    }
    
    public func setProgress(_ v: CGFloat, animated: Bool) {
        
        CATransaction.begin()
        if !animated {
            // disable CALayer "built-in" animation
            CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        }
        self.progress = v
        CATransaction.commit()
        
    }
    
    private let backgroundLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let foregroundLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let ticksLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    private let lineWidth: CGFloat = 15
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        // properties common to all layers
        [backgroundLayer, foregroundLayer, ticksLayer].forEach { lay in
            lay.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            layer.addSublayer(lay)
        }
        
        backgroundLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        foregroundLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        ticksLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        
        backgroundLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        foregroundLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        ticksLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY)
        let w: CGFloat = bounds.width - lineWidth
        let h: CGFloat = bounds.height - lineWidth * 0.5
        let radius: CGFloat = min(w * 0.5, h)
        let startAngle: CGFloat = .pi
        let endAngle: CGFloat = 0.0
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        
        backgroundLayer.path = path.cgPath
        foregroundLayer.path = path.cgPath
        
        let tickInnerRadius: CGFloat = radius - lineWidth * 0.5
        let tickOuterRadius: CGFloat = radius + lineWidth * 0.5
        
        let tickInnerPath = UIBezierPath()
        let tickOuterPath = UIBezierPath()
        let tickPath = UIBezierPath()
        
        // 20-degree tick spacing
        let angleInc: CGFloat = .pi / 9.0
        
        // start at 270-degrees minus 4 * spacing
        var angle: CGFloat = .pi * 1.5 - angleInc * 4.0
        
        for _ in 1...7 {
            tickOuterPath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: tickOuterRadius, startAngle: angle, endAngle: angle + angleInc, clockwise: true)
            tickInnerPath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: tickInnerRadius, startAngle: angle, endAngle: angle + angleInc, clockwise: true)
            tickPath.move(to: tickOuterPath.currentPoint)
            tickPath.addLine(to: tickInnerPath.currentPoint)
            angle += angleInc
        }
        
        ticksLayer.path = tickPath.cgPath
        
        foregroundLayer.strokeEnd = progress
        
    }
    
}
```

and an example controller with some "percent buttons" and a slider to change the Progress percentage:

```
class HalfCircleTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let hcpView = HalfCircleProgressView()
    
    // add a label to show the progress percent
    let pctLabel = UILabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        
        // we want the arc to be inset a bit, so we'll embed it in a "container"
        let container = UIView()
        container.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(container)
        
        hcpView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        container.addSubview(hcpView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            container.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
            container.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            // let's inset our progress view by 40-points on each side
            hcpView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            hcpView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            // give hcpView a 2:1 ratio
            hcpView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hcpView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0 / 2.0),
            
            hcpView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        pctLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(pctLabel)
        // add the pctLabel in the middle of the arc
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pctLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hcpView.centerXAnchor),
            pctLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hcpView.centerYAnchor),
        ])
        
        // let's add some percent / progress buttons
        let btnStack = UIStackView()
        btnStack.spacing = 4
        btnStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        [0.0, 0.1, 0.25, 0.33, 0.61, 0.8, 1.0].forEach { v in
            let b = UIButton()
            b.setTitle("\(v)", for: [])
            b.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            b.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
            b.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 13.0, weight: .bold)
            b.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
            b.layer.cornerRadius = 6
            b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            btnStack.addArrangedSubview(b)
        }
        
        btnStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(btnStack)
        
        // let's add a slider to set the progress
        let slider = UISlider()
        slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(slider)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            btnStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btnStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btnStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            slider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnStack.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            slider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        sliderChanged(slider)
        
        container.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }
    
    func updatePercentLabel() {
        let pct = hcpView.progress
        pctLabel.text = String(format: "%0.2f %%", pct * 100.0)
    }
    
    @objc func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let t = sender.currentTitle {
            let v = (t as NSString).floatValue
            // set progress directly
            //  this will use CALayer "built-in" animation
            hcpView.progress = CGFloat(v)
            updatePercentLabel()
        }
    }
    @objc func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        // we want to update the progress WHILE dragging the slider
        //  so, set progress WITHOUT animation
        //  otherwise, we get a "lag"
        hcpView.setProgress(CGFloat(sender.value), animated: false)
        updatePercentLabel()
    }
    
}
```

It will look like this when running:

[image]

Comment: Amazing answer, learned a lot! really grateful for the effort you put on the answer.